# UILabel splitting

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, split, label

if I have a UILabel: label1.text (maximum length 6 character) In this example GARAGE is the word in it.

is it possible to have code that would make

```
label1a: G
label1b: A
label1c: R
label1d: A
label1e: G
label1f: E
```

I need this so I can compare every character in a word with every character in  a other word.

Been struggling with this for a couple of days now :S

**edit**

I got a random word generator that generates word with a length of 6 like 'GARAGE' or 'SAILOR' it generates it into a label for this We'll call the label: 'randomword.text'

now We got a input label where the character display that we put in with our own made keyboard. this label is 'input.text'

now we can compare those 2 labels with if (randomword.text == input.text') { NSLog: @'these words are the same' };

What I want to do is to seperate every letter in random.text: so have label1 say G, label2 say A, label3 say R, label4 say A, label5 say G, label6 say E.

If I separate my input.text in the same way like I did above with random.text I got another 6 UILabel for example have this one separated in label7,8,9,10,11,12. Now I can compare label 1 to label 7, label 2 to 8. etc That way I can see if Letters are on the place they should be even if the entire word do not equal each other.

Comment: so basically you wants all characters of label's text, correct?

Comment: yes I want them seperated automaticly so I can compare them but it has to be automatic since the word in label1 is different everytime with a random word generator but I got that all working fine already

Comment: if you want to split string into characters then you can use -

    for(int i =0 ;i<[myString length]; i++) {
        char = [myString characterAtIndex:i];
    }

Comment: although it seems to me like you need something else with it also which i am not getting.Can you elaborate some more?

Comment: I don't have code avaiable ATM, since im not at my home. But I have a label1.text with a length of 6, Random words generate into that with a random word generator for example the word GARAGE. now I have another label in what I input words with a length of 6. I want to compare every character in the 2 words to eachother So I want to seperate every character in every word into their own label So I can compare the labels with length 1. I've got the code for doing it with strings but how would I change label1.text into NSString *string1?

Comment: you can try with splitting string in to single character string and then achieve this with what you have done earlier?

Comment: So i'll make label1.text a string? how is that done

Comment: I don't get what you want at all. Please tell something about the functionality from a user's point of view.

Comment: I want 6 labels with 1 letter in them. and 1 label with 1 word in it with a length of 6 characters. Now the first label gets the first letter from the word, the second labels is the second letter in the word. etc. I need to compare every character in the word.. so I need them seperated

Comment: I edited by question with more explain hope you understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still confused by all that stuff about labels. I don't think your question has anything to do with labels, but with comparing strings or parts of them. So if you wan't to check if to strings are equal use

`[aString isEqualToString:anotherString];` (not ==).

If you want to extract a letter from a string use

`[aString characterAtIndex:i];` or `[aString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, i+1)]` .

If you want to check  if a letter is on a certain position (say i) in a string use:

```
NSString *aLetter;
[[aString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, i+1)] isEqualToString:aLetter];
```

or

```
unichar aLetter;
[aString characterAtIndex:i] == aLetter;
```

If you want to get 'what's shown on a `UILabel`' as `NSString` use `aLabel.text` .

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you sir It's hard for me to explain because I got alot of code and alot of actions so it will be hard to implent this in my code aswell but as soon as I get home tonight Im gonna work on it again thank you I'll let you know if it worked! If it did im gonna make a clear understandable thing about what I did at the question for every1 else haha thank you!